# Invalid pre-telease train when distibute app to app store

Tags: flutter, xcode

[image]

how to solve that error code when invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.0.6' is closed for new build submissions, invalid Version. The build with the version "1.0.7" can't be imported because a later version, and This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString 11.0.61 in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.0.71.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the bundle id from 1.0.7 to 2.0.0 as your previous build is approved with version 1.0.0 new builds will greater then this